# Facebook Like button Jquery Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I have a little problem hopefully someone can help with :)

I have a  **Facebook like button on a page**, that I would like to, when **'clicked'** to display a form underneath it. So far I have tried `.click` and it doesn't work, however, `.hover` does! But I don't want it that way.

Any info would be greatly appreciated!

(for testing purposes the like button doesn't refer to any page yet, also for facebook script to work needs to be on a server, localhost or otherwise)

Here is my code:

```
 <!-- Add Jquery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <!--My styles -->
   <style>
    #form{display: none;width:400px;}

    </style>

 <!-- Facebook Code -->
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>

 <!-- MY click Event -->
         <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".fb-like").click(function(){ //click doesnt work, hover does
                    $("#form").css("display","block");
                });
             });

            </script>

    <!-- the Button -->
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="#" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>

   <!-- The Form -->
   <form id="form">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="First Name"><br>
        <input type="email" name="email" value="Your Email">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A scratch my previous answer. I looked again and found out that the like button is rendered in an iframe. That means it is protected by first origin policy and you CANNOT access DOM components on another domain. Tough luck.

Comment: awwwww that sucks!  thanks very much for the detective work though, saved me another countless hours trying to make it work.

Comment: Yeah. I am a little heartbroken myself. I was planning to do the same as you on a project later on.Not going to happen looks like. Thanks for the vote.